# How to map right/left click scroll down/up to F1 F2 F3 F4?

Tags: shortcuts, accessibility, remapping

I want to map, remap or create a shortcut that:

F1 : Right click

F2 : Left click

F3 : Scroll Down

F4 : Scroll Up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `xmodmap` and `xdotool`, and I made the best use of them. `xmodmap` is better for left and right click. Shortcut using `xdotool` is better for scroll down and up.

I will show all steps to let the user decide which keys and buttons they want to remap.

## 0 - Discover keys names

**With `xev` you discover:**

F1 : keycode 67

F2 : keycode 68

F3 : keycode 69

F4 : keycode 70

Left click: Pointer_Button1

Right click: Pointer_Button3

Scroll Down: Pointer_Button5

Scroll Up:   Pointer_Button6

## 1 - Use F1 and F2 to left and right click

Use `xmodmap` to really remap keys (better than shortcuts, because it allows drag and drop)

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 67 = Pointer_Button3"
xmodmap -e "keycode 68 = Pointer_Button1 Pointer_Button1"
```

*This solution derived partially from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070643/how-to-map-a-key-to-work-like-mouse-button-including-its-modifiers/1070710#1070710).*

## 2 - Create shortcuts for scroll down and up

keyboard > shortcuts > "+" > ...

Scroll down and shortcut F3

```
xdotool click 5
```

Scroll up and shortcut F4

```
xdotool click 4
```

## **Restore default configuration of xmodmap:**

```
setxkbmap -option
```

Comment: This is great, really, but now I have my keypad off. How to map F1/F2 keys as clicks and be able to use numeric keypad please ?

Comment: @MévatlavéKraspek unfortunatelly I still dont have the answer... I simply stopped using keypad... If you find the solution please share.

Comment: How to map middle mouse button (pressing scroll wheel)?

Comment: @blueray I had to use a python script to do it. I used pyautogui. I didnt find anything only using bash.