# How to map a key to work like mouse button including its modifiers?

Tags: xmodmap, accessibility, remapping

With xmodmap I can map F2 to work as left click:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 68 = Pointer_Button1"
```

However, when I use shift+F2 to simulate shift left-click to select files on nautilus for example, it doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't test this one, but a common issue (also occurring with xdotool equivalents) is that you are virtually pressing the shortcut PLUS the targeted key or mousebutton. Many times fixed when you add a break of let's say 0.5 between pressing and the actual targeted (virtual) action.

Comment: I have no idea how to test it on xmodmap @JacobVlijm . I'm trying to find how to map a key to reproduce a key combination.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I know that this feature is possible because when I use universal access to use keypad to control the mouse, "5" simulates left-click on all its aspects

Comment: I am afraid you are misunderstanding, if you call a ke by (another) key, you are actually virtually pressing both the real one and the one you call. It depends on if the combination isn't disabling the latter. Very well possible it worked with 5.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I already solved the problem as you can see in my answer. When I said it was possible to do, I meant that if someone made 5 to work as left-click, I can make F2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nothing is defined for its modifier, when shift+F2 is pressed, nothing happens.

So:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 68 = Pointer_Button1 Pointer_Button1"
```