# Use Control+Right Alt+Arrows to change workspaces

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I've been using workspaces with gnome and Ubuntu 18.04, and I would like to change the shortcuts to switch workspaces. I've seen that dconf-editor has an option to do it in org > gnome > desktop > wm > keybindings, and the default is

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys.

For some reason, this <kbd>Alt</kbd> only works with the Left Alt and not Right Alt. I would like to switch it for Right Alt, since then I may only use one hand. Did anyone try to do the same thing? I appreciate any ideas.

One last thing, when I run `xev` in the terminal Right Alt appears as `ISO_LEVEL3_SHIFT`, so I'm guessing that the name of some keys in Ubuntu are non-standard.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried keyboard> shortcuts> navigation> switch workspaces???

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The option settings> devices> keyboard> shortcuts> navigation> move workspaces, only allow moving up and down in the grid, and they don't seem to register the right alt key to define a shortcut. So, this doesn't do what I wanted.

Comment: So try to map left alt to right alt using xmodmap.

Comment: Use xmodmap part of my answer to discover and remap right alt. https://askubuntu.com/a/1070272/530032

Comment: that's also not an option, because I need the function of the right alt key to write some symbols/characters. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post provides a few options to fix the problem:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1936999#p1936999

The simplest option seems to be to go to `Gnome Settings => Keyboard Shortcuts => Alternate Characters Key` and select a key other than Right Alt. Then the Right Alt key will start working again for the change workspace shortcut.